# Using LIKE in mysql where the data is a string with a delimeter

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multiple select with the options going into a table with a delimeter `***` so the data in the field `s_industry` is like this:

```
Social Care***Healthcare***Nursing***
```

My SQL query is like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `jobs` 
LEFT JOIN `employers` ON `jobs`.`user_id`=`employers`.`user_id`
WHERE (`jobs`.`primary_sector` LIKE '%pr%' OR `jobs`.`secondary_sector` LIKE '%pr%') 
OR (`jobs`.`primary_sector` LIKE '%dentist%' OR `jobs`.`secondary_sector` LIKE '%dentist%') OR (`jobs`.`primary_sector` LIKE '%marketing%' OR `jobs`.`secondary_sector` LIKE '%marketing%') 
AND `jobs`.`location` LIKE '%Manchester%' 
AND `jobs`.`archived`='0' 
AND `jobs`.`featured`='0' ORDER BY `jobs`.`job_id
```

I could but some space either side of say % pr % but that won't ignore the `***`. Is there a way I can get the `***` to be treated as a space, or another solution?

Answer (score 2):

Not being facetious but this suggests a bad underlying DB design.  Any chance you're able to revise it? This sort of query is precisely why we normalise database content, i.e. split into tables where **t_sector** would be a lookup table and jobs would link to it via, say, **t_job_sector**, one entry per sector mapping.

Comment: Yeah I could change it, but I have no idea one you just said. Should I be researching lookup tables?

Comment: @jhodgson4 Yes, It would be really good if you could learn more about database normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Great thanks, anything I can do as a quick fix to get it working?

Comment: Strongly urge look at your DB design; this is pretty good introduction to what I'm talking about: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/